# Re-translate Django

Tags: django

Django comes translated in my language however I don't like some of the translated phrases (personal preference).

So I set the `locale` folder up and run `python manage.py makemessages -l fa_IR` and I get the file `django.po` but when I open it, I find that the phrases that are already translated and included with Django are not there.

So looks like I have to edit (for example) `\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\locale\fa\LC_MESSAGES\django.po` but if I ever update Django package of this project, all my edits will be lost, right? Or there's a way to have all phrases in my `locale\django.po` and translate them again?

Another challenge for me is that some of the permissions for built-in models are not marked for translation. So do I have to subclass all of them and add the translation myself?

[image]

Comment: I add some additional info to answer on your question

Comment: It will help you if you carefully read my post. I clearly said I want to re-translate what is already translated by Django team.

Answer (score -1):

Your existed locals in project/locals can not be overriden, if you reinstall django. After reinstall django should take your translations if you setup all correct. But, it can be, that New Django have new text for translations and remove old. In this case your local.po have OLD translations and did'not have any new.

Probably you should repeate **makemessages**:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages

after *makemessages*, check translations, which you want to translate.
After made **compilemessages**:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages

After - **runserver**. All schould be translated.
If something is not translated - you are not mark this text as translatable text.

Please don't forget, makemessages NOT remove old existed translations, you can have something, what not used in django now. And also remember upper/lowercase or punctuation are important. The "Post" and "post" and "Post." they all not the same.

Date in field **name** in *Class **Permission*** - was never marked for translations for logical reasons - it is not static data, which can be collected by **maketranslations**. D:\Projects\humanai_auth.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py
You should organize data translation itself.

To translate data of any Model in Django - you shouild use external library. *For example - i have created [Django-TOF](https://github.com/danilovmy/django-tof). Also i add in my library, translation on fly the static texts.*